# MY SQL : please confirm if my query is right else provide right query

Tags: mysql

i using this query but  test case not passed

```
select ct.name,cm.name,sl.quantity 
from sales as sl 
inner join country as ct on sl.country_id=ct.id 
inner join car_model as cm on cm.id=sl.model_id 
where sl.sales_date BETWEEN '01-01-2020' AND '12-31-2020' 
order by ct.quantity asc;
```

[image]

Comment: If this is MySQL, then those aren't dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
      ct.name,
      cm.name,
      sl.quantity 
   from 
      sales as sl 
         inner join country as ct 
            on sl.country_id = ct.id 
         inner join car_model as cm 
            on sl.model_id = cm.id 
   where 
      sl.sales_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' 
   order by 
      sl.quantity asc;
```

Comment: Good attempt.  Just fixed date-format for SQL.  Normal is YYYY-MM-DD format.  Also, formatted for readability.  When posting, and future of your SQL writing you can directly see the references of the sections by indentation.  Select, From, Where, Order and what each of those parts are.  Indenting JOINS is also good to see how/where each table is related in a hierarchical orientation.  When using multiple tables, ALWAYS use the table/alias for column name references for those who dont know your table structures.